# Unital homomorphism to semisimple Banach algebra is automatically continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

I need to prove that any unital  homomorphism $\phi: A \to B$, where $A$ is unital  Banach algebra and $B$ is semisimple Banach algebra is continuous.

The definition of "semisimple" I know is that the kernel of Gelfand transform which is the same as $ \{b \in B: \sigma(b) = 0 \}$ equals $\{0 \}$.

I am asking for some hint. Also may be I am not aware of some result needed.

Comment: Aren't Banach algebra homomorphisms often assumed to be continuous? What is your definition?

Comment: @Cameron Williams, just homorphism as algebras (I didn't mean morphism in category Banach algebras)

Comment: See chapter 6, section 2 in [Banach and Locally Convex Algebras by Helemskii, A.Ya.](http://bookfi.net/book/2242228) There is a lot on these matters at the end of that section.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite right as stated.

Johnson proved that a surjective homomorphism *onto* a semi-simple Banach algebra is automatically continuous. (For the proof see, *e.g.*, Theorem 5.1.5 in Dales' *[Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity](https://books.google.pl/books?id=WZ6DQgAACAAJ&dq=banach%20algebra%20and%20automatic%20continuity&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpgay1x7_cAhVFFSwKHQiLBkUQ6AEIKDAA)*.)

Apparently, it is an open problem whether it is enough to assume that the homomorphism considered has dense range (Question 5.1.A in Dales' book).